# Update dictionary/list with same key but different value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Any kind of assistance will be appreciable. I am trying to achieve the following for encryption purpose using keys, not sure how to write code using  dictionary/list, I need an update function to loop around and check which key being used to encrypt files, I am trying to achieve as this example

My try:

```
dict = {}
x = {}
y = {}

# already have this value
dict = {"keyfile1": "encryptfile1"}
print(dict)

# want to check if value already exist and update accordingly
while True:
  x = input("Enter key value: ")
  y = input("Enter file name: ")
  dict[x] = y
  dict.update({x: y})  # it's not updating with same key value

  # dict.setdefault(x, []).append(y)    # try this but throwing AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' 

  print(dict)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean "it's not updating with same key value"? Show an *exact* example of things that the user types, *exactly* what happens as a result of *each separate* attempt, and explain *exactly how this is different from what you actually want*. For example, show exactly what should be contained in the dict afterwards, vs. what is actually contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
encrypt_key_value_dict = {}

encrypt_key_value_dict = {"keyfile1": ["encryptfile1"]}
print(encrypt_key_value_dict)

while True:
    x = input("Enter key value: ")
    y = input("Enter file name: ")
    if x in encrypt_key_value_dict:
        encrypt_key_value_dict[x].append(y)
    else:
        encrypt_key_value_dict[x]=[y]
  
print(encrypt_key_value_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a `defaultdict` with this.

Here's how it works:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Factory is a list class, which will be called when inserting into the dict object
encrypt_key_value_dict = defaultdict(list, {"keyfile1": ["encryptfile1"]})

print(encrypt_key_value_dict)

while True:
  x = input("Enter key value: ")
  y = input("Enter file name: ")
  
  """
  Here you can append to the list immediately, because the value from
  the defaultdict is programmatically evaluated as a list object
  """
  encrypt_key_value_dict[x].append(y)

  print(encrypt_key_value_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

you may use multidict for your needs https://multidict.readthedocs.io/en/stable/multidict.html#multidict

Comment: While this is a hint, I don't find it to be very helpful. Consider editing to show how a multidict solves the issue.